# Connect R to Spark through sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to connect R to Spark following the `sparklyr` tutorial from RStudio: http://spark.rstudio.com/

But some how, I'm getting a weird error message as below. Does anyone knows how to solve this ?
I have tried to add the `C:\Windows\system32` path to the System Variables Path without any success. Thanks for your help.

```
> library(sparklyr)
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
Error in sparkapi::start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home,  : 
  Failed to launch Spark shell. Ports file does not exist.
    Path: C:\Users\Gaud\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit.cmd
    Parameters: --jars, "C:\Users\Gaud\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\sparklyr\java\sparklyr.jar", --packages, "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0","com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34", sparkr-shell, C:\Users\Gaud\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC8MAa8\file322c47ee2a28.out
```

Comment: I've only used R and Spark a few times, so I'm not sure how to solve your issue, but I would highly recommend signing up for Databricks community edition which "save" you from much of the headaches required in running spark on Windows.  They also have R notebooks which are pretty savvy. https://databricks.com/try-databricks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently. This bug was discussed at [RStudio GitHub sparklyr pages](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/229).

Could you please provide your `sessionInfo()` results?
Its output sheds the light on the package versions and OS in use.

2 main points which helped me:

- Install Spark using `spark_install()`
- Install dev. edition of sparklyr using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")`

Check the version of the sparklyr package.
In my case the problem disappeared only after updating to version `sparklyr_0.4.11`.

Answer (score 1):

Install the **latest sparklyr** from github repository.

**Steps to install sparklyr, if you don't have internet on your server.**

- Install R packages devtools and git2r
- Download the master zip file from git
- Unzip it on a windows path
- Create a source: source <- devtools:::source_pkg("windows path/master
  directory name")
- install(source)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to make sure you have the most current version of RStudio, if that's what you're using (download and install after closing RStudio from here): https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

```
    library(DBI)
    library(lazyeval)
    library(dplyr)
    library(devtools)
    # install_github("rstudio/sparkapi")
    library(sparkapi)
    # install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")
    library(sparklyr)
    library(yaml)
    library(nycflights13)

    # Note: Only perform Spark once
    spark_install(version = "1.6.1")

    # Connect to Spark through connection
    sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
    iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, "iris", overwrite = TRUE)
    flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights", overwrite = TRUE)
    class(flights_tbl)


 flights_preview <- DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT * FROM flights LIMIT 10")
    flights_preview
```

Will output this in Windows 10:

```
# year month day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin
# 1  2013     1   1      517            515         2      830            819        11      UA   1545  N14228    EWR
# 2  2013     1   1      533            529         4      850            830        20      UA   1714  N24211    LGA
# 3  2013     1   1      542            540         2      923            850        33      AA   1141  N619AA    JFK
# 4  2013     1   1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18      B6    725  N804JB    JFK
# 5  2013     1   1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25      DL    461  N668DN    LGA
# 6  2013     1   1      554            558        -4      740            728        12      UA   1696  N39463    EWR
# 7  2013     1   1      555            600        -5      913            854        19      B6    507  N516JB    EWR
# 8  2013     1   1      557            600        -3      709            723       -14      EV   5708  N829AS    LGA
# 9  2013     1   1      557            600        -3      838            846        -8      B6     79  N593JB    JFK
# 10 2013     1   1      558            600        -2      753            745         8      AA    301  N3ALAA    LGA
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/114, the following worked for me:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = list())
```